# Why popular package invariant.js contains this code: error.framesToPop = 1;

Tags: javascript, facebook

[invariant.js](https://github.com/zertosh/invariant/blob/master/invariant.js) contains this code:

```js
error.framesToPop = 1;
```

I've googled all day, I can't found a proper explanation.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) didn't mention this as well.

I know the package says:

```js
// we don't care about invariant's own frame
```

but I tried it at codepen, it still shows that function in error message

[image]

```js
function test() {
  let myError = new Error('my error')
  myError.name = 'my error name'
  myError.framesToPop = 1;
  throw myError
}

function main() {
  test()
}

main()
```

```
at test (pen.js:10:17)
```

Is it really a thing?

Comment: Apparently, this is something internal at Facebook: https://twitter.com/joshwnj/status/578062208283717632?lang=en

Comment: I've read this thread as well, but still can't get it, so if this is internal at facebook,  when I'm writing my own library with my own version of invariant, I don't have to include this line right? I've see other version of invariant has same code, like this one: [invariant.ts](https://github.com/apollographql/invariant-packages/blob/master/packages/ts-invariant/src/invariant.ts)

Comment: I would say yes: I think that except if you work at Facebook, this variable seems to be worthless!